# How to correctly parse JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I use Databricks to get delta table info and I return the result as a JSON. The return goes by `return json.dumps(value)`. However, when I receive the JSON it looks like `'key': 'value'`, with single quotes. Also, the booleans are displayed as `True`, `False` while `null` is displayed as `None` (which is normally since this is the way Python returns things). After receiving it into Python (precisely, Flask app), I forward this JSON to my .NET app but before that, I clean it with the following way:

```
json_value = json_value.replace("'", '"')
json_value = json_value.replace('True', 'true')
json_value = json_value.replace('False', 'false')
json_value = json_value.replace('None', 'null')
```

This thing worked for 2 months until one of my records got `Cote d'Ivore` as a value. This 'cleaning' replaced the single quote here with a double quote and that made my JSON crash on the .NET side. I parse the JSON on the .NET side by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content)`.

Now, is there some automatic way to parse the JSON correctly at the Python side, without having to clean it by replacing and have a proper functionality when I'd send it to .NET?

Comment: How did you create `json_value`? It should not be a string at this point, but a deserialized JSON object (such as `list` or `dict`). Then the forwarding can trivially be done via `json.dumps()`.

Comment: It looks like your `json_value` is string.  You should use dict intead, and then it is properly converted to json by json.dump

Comment: Yes, `json_value` is a string. I see, will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a dictionary object in `json.dumps()` instead of a string.

```
import json
a={'s':'asdas','fff':23,'ss':True, 'sssss':None}
res=json.dumps(a)
print (res)
##OUTPUT
## {"s": "asdas", "fff": 23, "ss": true, "sssss": null}
```

Assuming that you have string instead of a python dictionary; in that case you can convert that to dictionary using `ast` library

```
import ast
import json
value="{'s': 'asdas', 'fff': 23, 'ss': True, 'sssss': None}"
 #assuming it is in string format
value=ast.literal_eval(value) #convert string format dictionary to dictionary 
result=json.dumps(value)
```